# CFG for a given languague

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, language-design

Give a CFG for the languague L = $ \{ 1^n +1^m = 1^{n+m}| n,m \in N_{0}\} $ , with the alphabet $\Sigma =\{1,+,=\}$.

I am currently trying to solve the given task, I thought a good way is to split the Languague into two more simple languagues, but I am keep failing. May some can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to start generating the ones of the first addend from the axiom $S$, while simultaneously adding the corresponding number of ones at the end of the sentential form. Then you have a production from $S$ to non-terminal $A$ which takes care of generating the second added, while still appending ones at the end of the sentential form.

When you are done generating the second addend you can replace $A$ with $=$ in order to split all the ones from the two addends (on the left side) from the corresponding number of ones on the right size.

$$
\begin{align*}
S &\to 1S1 \mid +A \\
A &\to 1A1 \mid \,=
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Hello Steven, thx for your answer. But you did not consider that n/m can be 0.

Comment: Why not?  Here is an example where $n=0$: $S \to +A \to +1A1 \to +1=1$. Here is an example where $m=0$: $S \to 1S1 \to 1+A1 \to 1+=1$. Here is an example where $n=m=0$: $S \to +A \to +=$.

Comment: Ohh, you are right. My fault, thank you very much.

Comment: Since I am not able to upvote/declare this answer as correct, I will write it here : The answer from Steven is completly correct.